# dex2jar jd-gui decompilaton issue

Tags: android, apk, decompiling

I wanted to see the source code for an **apk** file created which I did by using dex2jar to transform the **dex** file in to a .class file, and then use a jar **decompiler** (such as the free jd-gui) to plain text java.

Now for viewing that source code I added the classes.dex.dex2jar as an external jar in the project and started viewing the .class files of the external jar added. Now the issue is, in the code there are some statements like:

```
1 local1 = new 1(this);
2 local2 = new 2(this);
3 local3 = new 3(this);
```

Can anyone help how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to creating 3 inner classes, like so:

```
public class test000021_innerclass {
    void X() {
        innerClass1 c1 = new innerClass1(this);
        innerClass2 c2 = new innerClass2(this);
        innerClass3 c3 = new innerClass3(this);
    }

    private class innerClass1 {

        public innerClass1(test000021_innerclass test000021_innerclass) {
        }
    }

    private class innerClass2 {

        public innerClass2(test000021_innerclass test000021_innerclass) {
        }
    }

    private class innerClass3 {

        public innerClass3(test000021_innerclass test000021_innerclass) {
        }
    }
}
```